# AWS S3 Buckets: CORS configuration issue (XML vs. JSON)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Looks like AWS no along accepts XML format for the CORS policy for the S3 Bucket.
Below is the original policy.
Can anyone help me with converting this to JSON format?
Thank you!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
<CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>HEAD</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
    <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
    <ExposeHeader>Access-Control-Allow-Origin</ExposeHeader>
    <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule>
<CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
</CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the following code:

```
[
    {
      "origin": ["*"],
      "method": ["GET","POST","PUT"],
      "responseHeader": ["*"],
      "MaxAgeSeconds": 3000,
      "ExposeHeaders": "Access-Control-Allow-Origin"
    }
]
```

I tested this with the commands:

$ gsutil cors set sample.json  gs://bucketname
Setting CORS on gs://bucketname/...
$ gsutil cors get  gs://bucketname
[{"method": ["GET", "POST", "PUT"], "origin": ["*"], ...

Answer (score 4):

```
[
{
    "AllowedHeaders": [
        "*"
    ],
    "AllowedMethods": [
        "PUT",
        "POST",
        "DELETE"
    ],
    "AllowedOrigins": [
        "*"
    ],
    "ExposeHeaders": [
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin"
    ],
    "MaxAgeSeconds": 3000
},
{
    "AllowedHeaders": [
        "*"
    ],
    "AllowedMethods": [
        "GET"
    ],
    "AllowedOrigins": [
        "*"
    ]
}
]
```